# Accessing variable outside of scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

I understand that this question has already been asked before; however, I am still having trouble with this concept. As you can see, the first function works when setting 'profile' to a global variable, but when I try and mimic that same result with the second function, I run into trouble. I get a `resultArray is not defined` error.

```js
function profileloader() {
  profile = []; // no "var" makes this global in scope
  profile[0] = "Joe";
  profile[1] = "Bloggs";
  profile[2] = "images/joeb/pic.jpg";
  profile[3] = "Web Site Manager";
}
profileloader(); // mandatory
document.write("Firstname is: " + profile[0]);

function pressme() {
  $.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

    //Testing to see if response returns correctly
    var response = (data);
    console.log(response);
    resultArray = [];
    resultArray[0] = response.country_name;
    console.log(resultArray[0]);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = response.country_name;
  });
}

pressme();
document.write("Country is: " + resultArray[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3> Returns Country of Origin from users IP Address</h3>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This isn't a problem of scope (although relying on global variables is not great), it's a problem with timing. You are trying to eat the pizza before it was delivered.